# in some movie,Description is null then i want to set "not available" there.so how can i do this?

Tags: java, android, json

```
private void getDATA(String json) throws JSONException {

moviename = new ArrayList<>();
Currentmovie c = new Currentmovie();
String story = "About The Story";

JSONArray values = new JSONArray(json);
for(int i = 0; i < values.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = values.getJSONObject(i);

    String movieTitle = jsonObject.getString("Title");
    String disc = jsonObject.getString("Description");
    Log.e(TAG,"GIRISH"+movieTitle);
    c= new Currentmovie();
    c.setTitle("Movie Name::"+movieTitle);
    c.setDesc(story+"::\n"+disc);
    if(jsonObject.getString("Description")==null)
    {
        c.setDesc(story+"::Not Available");
    }
    moviename.add(c);

}
```

//(disc == null) is also not working,(disc.equalsto(null)) is also not working...
//in some movie,Description is null then i want to set "not available" there.so how can i do this?

Comment: if disc is null,, then why (disc == null) is not working, Is it blank, if yes, you can check for disc.isEmpty(),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your json string is:`{"Title":"One movie"}`

then `jsonObject.getString("Description")==null`

if your json string is:`{"Title":"One movie","Description":""}`

then `jsonObject.getString("Description").equals("")`

Comment: yes bro!!!i was doing silly mistake that jsonObject.getString("Description").equals(" ")  in which i was need to write jsonObject.getString("Description").equals("")

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private void getDATA(String json) throws JSONException {


moviename = new ArrayList<>();
Currentmovie c = new Currentmovie();
String story = "About The Story";

JSONArray values = new JSONArray(json);
for(int i = 0; i < values.length(); i++) {
JSONObject jsonObject = values.getJSONObject(i);

String movieTitle = jsonObject.getString("Title");
String disc = jsonObject.getString("Description");
Log.e(TAG,"GIRISH"+movieTitle);
c= new Currentmovie();
c.setTitle("Movie Name::"+movieTitle);
if(jsonObject.getString("Description")==null)
 {
   c.setDesc(story+"::Not Available");

 }else{
 if(jsonObject.getString("Description").equals("")
    {
      c.setDesc(story+"::Not Available");
    }else{
      c.setDesc(story+"::\n"+disc);
    }
 moviename.add(c);
```

Comment: yes bro!!! i have done...i hate those kind of people:: when you post any ques. they don;t try to solve,always try to downvote....but thank you and kerwin....